# Javascript issue inside HTML (popup gallery)

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, gallery

In the code below, when I click on one of the two images it opens a gallery, and if I click on the other one it should open a different gallery. It works, but not as I expected because as you can see on the snippet there are some empty slides in each gallery. Can you help me solve this problem? Thank you!

```js
// Get the image and insert it inside the modal
function imgg(id){
    var modal = document.getElementById(id);
  var modalImg = document.getElementById('mySlides');
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
   function clos(id) { 
    var modal = document.getElementById(id);
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// Sliseshow
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.mySlides {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px -6px #000;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 100px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .mySlides {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.w3-btn-floating {
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">


</head>
<body>

<img id="myImg" onClick="imgg('myModal')" src="http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="200">

<img id="myImg" onClick="imgg('myModal1')"src="http://cue.me/kohana/media/frontend/js/full-page-scroll/examples/imgs/bg2.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="200">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span onclick="clos('myModal')" class="close">×</span>
 <img class="mySlides" id="img_modal" src="http://cue.me/kohana/media/frontend/js/full-page-scroll/examples/imgs/bg2.jpg" >
 <img class="mySlides" id="img_modal" src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2015/11/images-from-the-2016-sony-world-pho/s01_130921474920553591/main_900.jpg" >

 <a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:45%;left:280px;" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</a>
 <a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:45%;right:280px;" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<div id="myModal1" class="modal">
  <span onclick="clos('myModal1')" class="close">×</span>
 <img class="mySlides" id="img_modal" src="http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg" >
 <img class="mySlides" id="img_modal" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/03/22/13/32738A6E00000578-3504412-image-a-6_1458654517341.jpg" >

 <a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:45%;left:280px;" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</a>
 <a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:45%;right:280px;" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suppose having the same id for multiple elements can cause problems. ids are meant to be unique, you can use another attribute like `data-gallery="123"` instead of id..

Comment: @Aziz how can I use it ? I don't now where to put my hands on, can you propose a edit to my code, so that I can understand more about it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but this line

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
```

should return 4 items. That would explain why you are getting 2 empty slides in your slider. Try filtering first by id (e.g. "myModal" or "myModal1") and afterwards get the number of the contained "mySlides"-classes.

so you can do it like this:

```
var activeModalId = "";
// Get the image and insert it inside the modal
function imgg(id){
    activeModalId = id;
    var modal = document.getElementById(activeModalId);
    var modalImg = modal.getElementsByClassName('mySlides');
    modal.style.display = "block";
    showDivs(0);
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
function clos() { 
    var modal = document.getElementById(activeModalId);
    modal.style.display = "none";
    activeModalId = "";
}

// Sliseshow
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementById(activeModalId).getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1;}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length;}
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

On top, you declare your active modal. It will be set, reused, and removed by your functions.

Comment: so it gives me empty slides because the id is the same... Is there a way to tell the function to get only the slides that are into the div with the ID that I used to call the function?

Comment: i think `document.getElementById("myModal").getElementsByClassName("mySlides")` should work

Comment: I changed like this:   "var x = document.getElementById("myModal").getElementsByClassName("mySlides")"   has you said, and now it works, but only with the first gallery(the one with ID "myModal"). I need it to work with each gallery so maybe there should be changes on   "document.getElementById("here")"  ?

Comment: of course, you have to do it dynamically, i'll edit my answer

Comment: Wow, now it works with the other one too! But now there is a different problem, when I click on the image to view the gallery it displays all the images in one slide and when I click on the arrow to change slide it starts working fine...

Comment: yes, because i'm stupid! take a look at modalImg in your imgg function. I edited it, so only the required slides get initialized. check updated answer.

Comment: Its the same now, I said it badly, in the first slide it shows all the images of the gallery I need, I try to explain: when I click on the image which call the function with id "myModal", it appears the gallery, but all the images of that gallery show up in the first slide. And when I click on an arrow the all thing get normal and it displays the images correctly ( one for each slide)

Comment: `var modalImg = modal.getElementsByClassName('mySlides')[0];` should do the trick

Comment: Just tried, its still like it, the only change it does it's that the "[0]" removes the first image from the gallery

Comment: check updated imgg-function in the answer... i'm just guessing here, it's hard to debug without seeing the error :D

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see there are some url typos.
For example: you have `ihttp` where it should be `http`.
In the mouse one there's an unnecessary url termination after `.jpg`: `?1448476701`

Comment: thank you, but that wasn't my real problem, I don't understand why there are empty spots in the galleries :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass "this" into function like

```
onClick="imgg('myModal',this)"
```

now in function get it

```
function imgg(id,this){
var modal = document.getElementById(id);
    var modalImg = document.getElementById('mySlides');
modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = this.src;}
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work in this way, it tells me "expected identifier"